# Unable to install scikit-survival

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn

I am not able to install scikit-survival in ec2. Can someone guide me.

Below is requirements.txt
astor==0.8.1
autograd==1.3
autograd-gamma==0.5.0
boto3==1.18.10
botocore==1.21.10
cycler==0.10.0
formulaic==0.2.4
future==0.18.2
greenlet==1.1.0
importlib-metadata==4.6.1
interface-meta==1.2.3
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==1.0.1
kiwisolver==1.3.1
lifelines==0.26.0
matplotlib==3.4.2
numpy==1.21.1
pandas==1.3.1
Pillow==8.3.1
psycopg2==2.7.7
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.1
s3transfer==0.5.0
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.7.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.22
threadpoolctl==2.2.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
urllib3==1.26.6
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.5.0
osqp
numexpr
cvxpy
cvxopt
scikit-survival

Error Message:

```
 gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isksurv/bintrees -I/tmp/pip-build-env-fiwucdvq/overlay/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/ec2-user/dev/bhumk_ml/env/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c sksurv/bintrees/_binarytrees.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/sksurv/bintrees/_binarytrees.o
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-survival
Failed to build scikit-survival
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-survival which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```